# Using ui.alert properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to include an alert before running a function that moves an entire row of data to a new sheet. I should mention that the function works without the alert code.

```
case "Rejected":
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var response = ui.alert('Are you sure?',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
        if (response == ui.Button.OK)
{
        reject();
}
```

It seems pretty simple, a window pops up, but when I click ok, nothing happens. I checked and checked the documentation/tutorials and I can't figure out what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Welcome. Please add a [mcve]. If you didn't try it yet, create a new spreadsheet, add a new script project and add to it only the code lines required to show the alert and add some console.log or Logger.log to help you debug your function.

Comment: So in case the user chofses the case "Rejected", and confirms with Ok that he is sure - you want to run the function reject(), but the function is not run? What is reject() supposed to do?

Comment: So in case the user chooses the case "Rejected", and confirms with Ok that he is sure - you want to run the function reject(), but the function does not run? What is reject() supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct (I tested it.)

Try to add some `console.log(response == ui.Button.OK);` to check what is happening. Or drop some `debugger;` statements and run the debugger.

First validate that you are indeed entering the `if` block (try adding another alert inside the `if` .) Next check if `reject()` is not silently failing.